# Did WH_CALLWNDPROC hooks performance dramatically decrease with Win10 (Compared to Win7)?

Tags: winapi, windows-10

We are in the process of upgrading our workstations to Win10 from Win7.  While investigating reports of performance degradation, I came to the conclusion it was caused by a WH_CALLWNDPROC hook installed by a third party.

I came to this conclusion based on the result of the following test application (Done in Delphi 10 Seattle)

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  SW : TStopWatch;
begin
  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  for I := 0 to 1000000 do
  begin
    if Combobox1.ItemIndex > 0 then
      Exit;
  end;
  sw.Stop;
  ShowMessage(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString);
end;
```

(For those unfamiliar with Delphi, TStopwatch uses QueryPerformanceFrequency/QueryPerformanceCounter APIs to get elapsed time)

The execution time for this method is

- Win10 : 1485 msecs
- Win7 : 4996 msecs

(Note : Both machine are on wildly different hardware and can't really be compared to eachother).

Now, if I add a hook before executing the same code

```
function MySystemWndProcHook(Code: Integer; wParam: WParam; lParam: LParam): LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  Result := CallNextHookEx(FHook, Code, wParam, LParam);
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, @MySystemWndProcHook, 0, GetCurrentThreadId)
end;
```

The execution time now becomes :

- Win10 : 19552 msecs (about 1300% longer)
- Win7 : 8682 msecs (about 75% longer)

Now, as I mentionned, both workstation are on different hardware, but I don't believe that alone could explain the difference.  Win10 has an i7 cpu while Win7 has an i3. If anything, I'd expect the i3 to take a bigger hit (less cache, less resource... )

So, did WH_CALLWNDPROC hooks get that much slower since Win7? 
A quick google search didn't seem to reveal any other report of this issue. Can anybody reproduce my results?
If it can't be reproduced, anyone has any idea what settings/conflicting application could be causing this? (Already tried disabling Windows Defender real time scanning and it didn't affect performance).

EDIT : This was tested under Win10 1803 64 bits. The test application itself was 32 bits.

EDIT2 : Same application compiled in 64 bits gives the following execution time.

- Win10 : 780 msecs / 10201 msecs.
- Win7  : 6419 msec / 9201 msecs.

EDIT3 : Interestingly enough, when running the application (32bits) as admin :

- Win10 : 12693 msecs / 18028 msecs

Also, (on yet another workstation), running as different user makes a difference :

- Win10(1809) / "standard user" : 9430 / 17440 msecs
- Win10(1809) / System : 5220 / 10160 msecs (Started remotely through PsExec)

EDIT4 : If ran as admin, the application will run faster from a USB key than from a hard disk. (Note : So far, I only tested on system with a single drive.  At this point, I wouldn't exclude that only the OS drive is slower.)

EDIT5 : I found out quite a few more things about this situation.
First, running "As Admin"(win10) causes the application to have a WH_CALLWNDPROCRET hook to be installed. I haven't found where it is coming from (OS, Delphi's framework, other app?). It is definitely not there when simply running the app.

The performance hit doesn't seem to be so much on the hook itself, but on its effect on SendMessage.

We are in contact with Microsoft's support, they have reproduced similar results (on a 100k loop instead of 1m) :

- Windows 7 - Without hook 0.018396 seconds.
- Windows 10 - Without hook 0.025102 seconds.
- Windows 7 - With hook 0.167941 seconds.
- Windows 10 - With hook 1.105929 seconds.

(Investigation still on-going so still no conclusions thus far)

Those result also suggest many of our workstations perform way worse than they should when there are no hooks involved.

Comment: Win10 in general has more overhead (Control Flow Guard etc.) but the overhead should not be that massive. Do you know if your system is running other applications with hooks? A debug hook perhaps?

Comment: @Anders As far as I can tell, there is no other hook involved. I installed my own global debug hook and all I received was notification for my own WH_CALLWNDPROC hook.  Now, debug hooks doesn't receive notification for debug hooks, unless I didn't test it right...). I also set a breakpoint into CallNextHookEx and every calls to it came from my own hooks. Though, to be honest, I don't know enough about global hooks to know whether that is evidence enough.

Comment: @KenBourassa I am not aware of any significant performance issue with WH_CALLWNDPROC hooks on Windows 10. The question I have is what does Combobox1.ItemIndex in the Delphi code actually do in terms of window messages sent to the combo box control.

Comment: One difference between Windows 7 and Windows 10 is that calling the next hook in the hook chain now involves calling back into kernel mode to obtain information about the next hook in the hook chain.
Unless there is some lock contention on the kernel side, I am not aware of any issue that would cause such wild differences in the time it takes to execute the application code.

Comment: Spy++ uses WH_CALLWNDPROC hooks to monitor sent window messages. It would be worth finding our if you see similar delays if you use Spy++ to monitor window messages sent to windows owned by your application.

Comment: This is not a common problem, so far you are the only one that seems to be having it.  Temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.  And keep in mind that if that makes a big difference then that's only because you made an executable file appear from seemingly nowhere.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT ComboBox1.ItemIndex is basically just a wrapper around `SendMessage(Handle, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0)`. You can also check my 5th edit for further details.

Comment: @HansPassant The issue was reproduced by 2 other parties at least in some form/extent.  So I would say I'm not the only one...  I might be the only one that has both a process that uses messages a little too much and users that are sensitive enough to the execution time of said process.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with `SendMessage`. Does Microsoft support any conclusions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, WH_CALLWNDPROC and WH_CALLWNDPROCRET hooks do degrade performance quite a bit.  And quite a bit more so in Win10 than it did in Win7.

Some of the performance hit is coming from the mitigation code for Spectre and Meltdown. Early reports from Microsoft suggest the rest is apparently from lock contention in the window manager (win32k*.sys).

As for the weird result I've got in my investigation :

- Running "As Admin" caused an additional hook to be installed in my application which explains the massive slowdown I witnessed
- Many of the test I did were in test machine accessed through a remote admin tool... which happens to install global WH_CALLWNDPROC/WH_CALLWNDPROCRET hook itself, which made my test result flawed.  Running locally "fixed" the results. Took me a while to find out about it since my application is 32 bits and the hooks were 64 bits,  so my application wasn't notified of them (but still incurred the performance hit).

2020-02-04 : I just received an update from Microsoft. Their engineer identified a few issues that contribute to the performance degradation. Current estimate for a Windows Insider version containing fixes is 2020H1, early 2020H2